# SQL text match (Conversion in where clause)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Table 1                  Table 2
DOB                      DOB
01/02/1972               01/02/1972               
12/05/1985               12/05/1985
00/00/1985               00/00/1985
00/00/1985               00/00/1985
00/05/1985
```

The data in this query already has to be matched on a full match to Surname table 1 to table 2 which I have done by inner joining the data.

The data in table 1 and table 2 also need to match if the forename in table 1 has the first two letters of the forename from table 2 and vise versa.

The first two parts are fine,

The issue is I need to combine these with the DOB match from both tables the date of birth in both tables is formatted dd/mm/yyyy but for the solution it has to be formatted in the match for example format 20060115.
Therefore a match (Format) criteria are as follows table 1 =**2006**0115 table 2 = **2007**0000  -Match,
table 1 =**200601**15 table 2 = **200701**00 - Match, table 1 = 20060115 table 2 = 20070115 - Match, Others no match.

I am getting a error - I think due to the data some of it having 00/01/1981 or 00/00/1981 for example Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

This is my query -

```sql
Select *
From [dbo].[table 1] as t1
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[table 2] AS t2
ON
t1.[surname] = t2.[surname] --Surname
where (substring (t1.[full_name],1,1) = substring (t2.[Name 1],1,1)) --forename
or
(substring (t2.[full_name],1,2) = substring (t2.[Name 1],1,2))
```

The next part needs to be DOB match......

I have tried - this is where I get the error

```
Case 
  when sl.[DOB] is null  then 1 
else  
    cast(year(sl.[DOB]) as varchar) 
  + right('0' +cast(month(sl.[DOB]) as varchar),2) 
  + right('0' + cast(day(sl.[DOB]) as varchar),2)
```

Comment: The query columns don't match the sample data. And the expected result is missing. Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Hello jarlh apologies these are the same as my above so table 1 and table 2. The case statement represents part of the conversion I was trying to achieve as stated in the above so it would be where for example 20061000 = 20061000 then match etc. I am trying to pull back all the records from table 1 that match table 2 on these criteria. The sample was an example of the DOB data that I am struggling with, the data has multiple columns.

Comment: According to the sample data Table1 has one single column, DOB. Table2 the same. The query involves unknown columns full_name etc.

Comment: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). As posted, your matching criteria, and even your data types, just aren't clear to me at all.